# Using Concat in TYPO3 Extbase Query

Tags: typo3, extbase

i am struggling a little challenge and i am wondering what the solution might be as I couldn't find an answer in the documentation.

Here is my current working query (part):

```
$constraints[] = $query->like('kategorie', '%'.$kategorie.'%');
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
$constraints[] = $query->like(CONCAT(',', kategorie, ','), '%,'.$kategorie.',%');
```

Which obviously doesn't work at all. : -)

Every Help is really appriciated. Hope someone know the right syntax. TYPO3 Version is latest 6.1

Thank's alot!

Comment: i still try to solve this one with typo3 4.5 and could not find any solution. at the end i use a own *statement* to build a concat query.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Extbase query generation didn't change in 6.0, so it's the same for 4.x and 6.x.

Maybe you misunderstand the way Extbase is builing the query.

```
$query->like('property', '%value%');
```

will return an object when %value% is contained in "property". Such a property must be defined in the domain model. You can only query properties that have a "getProperty" method in their domain model.

Looking at your code, I think you're finding a way to query for a value being present in a comma-separated value list? Then you would use

```
$query->in('kategorien', $kategorie);
```

**EDIT:**

Your specific problem seems to be that you are not using a true relation for assigning "Kategorien" to your entity. You're using a comma-separated list to hold references to another model. You're discouraged to do so, but it is technically possible and used in the TYPO3 core: The FrontendUser model has a property "usergroup" that works in the same way.

Please have a look at the FrontendUser model: https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/HEAD:/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Domain/Model/FrontendUser.php

The annotation of your Kategorien must be correct, e.g.:

```
/**
* @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\My\Extension\Domain\Model\Kategorien>
*/
protected $kategorien;
```

Also make sure that getKategorien is correct.

If you still have problems, keep in mind that the TCA definition must be working to have Extbase work correctly.

In my opinion, a best practise would be to use the category API introduced in TYPO3 6.0:
http://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_6.0#Category

Comment: thats right, but how its about a *concat*-command with extbase querys?

Comment: You mean you would want to query a concatenated field, e.g. first_name,last_name like %peter%?

Comment: Hi Lorenz, thanks for that. I already tried to use "in" - but then I get an error which say:  #1264678095: The "in" operator must be given a mutlivalued operand (array, ArrayAccess, Traversable). (More information) - might be a dumb question, but i am new to extbase and couldnt figure that out. i dont get it why my VAR must be multivalued?

Comment: What kind of object is your "kategorien". Is it just a comma-separated list? Then you can't use "in". You should not use comma-separated lists for multi-valued properties in Extbase but use a true relation.

Comment: In the Database kategorien (categories) ist a comma-seperated list, which is related to another table with all the categories. i still trying to fix this from a database point of view, but thats maybe the wrong to do it...